# How can I move existing records from parent table to newly created child table with the help of triggers (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger, beforeupdate

I want to create a trigger wherein the child table pulls all the exisiting records from parent table.

I have created child tables referencing the parent table primary key as foreign key in new table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger name
AFTER INSERT ON table_name(parent_table)
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   insert statement for child table;
END;
```

Above trigger is created for records which will be inserting post to child table creation, I would like to push all old records (which were present prior to child table creation) to the new child table. Will triggers help in pulling all the old records ?

Comment: Ya, that's pretty much it. Just create an trigger on insert in the parent table and add an insert query to the child tables.

Comment: But Crimson, after insert triggers were called post insertion in parent table,so new records will be reflected in child table. Similarly the parent table has thousands of old records, how those old records be retrieved to the child table ? Will these possible with triggers ?

Comment: @SuganyaG putting old records is a one time activity, just do it manually, it doesn't make sense to handle them in trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously NO!!

The `trigger` will start inserting records to the child table from the parent table post creation of `trigger`. Records inserted into parent table prior to `trigger` creation need to be inserted manually.

If you want to pull all records before the creation of `trigger` into child table from parent table then you need to write one-time `INSERT` query as following:

```
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE
SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE P 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CHILD_TABLE C WHERE P.PK = C.FK);
```

-- OR --

```
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE
SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE P 
WHERE P.PK IN 
(SELECT PK FROM PARENT_TABLE
MINUS
SELECT FK FROM CHILD_TABLE
)
```

Cheers!!